# Question on notation in Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation, brownian-motion

I' am reading about the zero set of Brownian motion from [Introduction to Stochastic Processes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158488651X) by Lawler.

Let $X_t$ be a Brownian motion and define the following random set:

> $Z=\{t:X_t=0\}$

Lawler then goes on to discuss the topological properties of this set $Z$. I'll quote from the book:

> One topological property the $Z$ satisfies is the fact that $Z$ is a closed set. This means that if a sequence of points $t_i\in Z$ and $t_i\to t$, then $t\in Z$. This follows from the continuity of the function $X_t$. For continuous function, if $t_i\to t$, then $X_t\to X$.

What does the $\to$ symbol mean?

Comment: it means 'converges to'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $\to$ means "converges to", that is $t_i\to t$ means $\lim_{i\to +\infty}t_i=t$.